# How to Know that reducer has finished its task

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to do file operations after reducer has finished its task in map reduce wordcount example.
So is there any standard method to know that reducer has finished its task?

Comment: When the job finishes, the reducer has completed

Comment: is there any standard method to find it?

Comment: Its just job.waitForCompletion.  The sample probably uses that.  Have you looked at the source?

Answer (score 1):

Override the *cleanup* method of your Reducer and do whatever you wish to do. The *cleanup* method is the last method that is called at the end of a Mapper/Reducer task. Below is an example of what the *cleanup* method looks like :

```
@Override
public void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    // do whatever you wish to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanup method of the Mapper/Reducer class allows you to execute code when the mapper/reducer has finished its task.

Comment: where to write the cleanup method can we able to write in reducer?

Comment: Yes,we can write inside reducer class.